# How to display the center of an image in a thumbnail

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, gallery, thumbnails

This is probably something very simple, yet I can't seem to figure it out. I am working on an image gallery where the images are sometimes in the portrait and sometimes in the landscape mode. For the gallery to look uniform, I need the thumbnails to be the same size and only upon a click, the full image will be displayed. I'm using Zurb Foundation and SCSS.
This is my code at the moment:

```
<div class="img-single column column-block">
   <a data-open="galleryModal">
   <img src="assets/img-01.jpg" class="thumbnail" alt="">
   </a>
</div>

.img-single {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;

    img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
}
```

At the moment, the image stretches to be 300px by 300px. I just need to display a thumbnail of the image with the image's centre to be displayed, and not distorted. I also tried adding `vertical-align: middle;` and played with max-width and max-height values, but it didn't do anything. How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

You may take advantage of the new `object-fit` CSS property and make the image appear as you want.

Here is some example code for you, showing the difference between the image placed using `object-fit` and the default image:

```css
.img-single {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img-single img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="img-single column column-block">
  <a data-open="galleryModal">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/458/354?image=0" class="thumbnail" alt="Image with object-fit" title="Image with object-fit">
  </a>
</div>

<img src="https://unsplash.it/458/354?image=0" alt="Just the image" title="Just the image">
```

You may also position the image differently within the `.img-single` container using the `object-position` property if you want.

Hope it helped.

PS: I also used the `overflow` property in such cases to avoid images from bleeding out. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you! I'll look into object-position and report back.

Comment: Sure, take you time.

Answer (score 0):

You can center the image in a smaller container using `background-image` on a `div`.

```
<div class="thumbnail" style="background: url("assets/img-01.jpg") no-repeat;"></div>

.thumbnail {
  background-position: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: But I have many images there so I would need to create multiple classes and use background image with each class, no? Isn't there a way to do it when having the images in my html, instead of a CSS?

Comment: What you can do is apply same class to all and apply the `background-image` url in the element itself using the `style` property in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

If you remove Foundation's `thumbnail` class this should work.

**HTML (e.g)**

```
<div class="img-grid row small-up-2 medium-up-3 large-up-4">
    <div class="img-single column column-block">
       <a data-open="galleryModal">
       <img src="https://placeimg.com/620/580/animals" class="" alt="">
       </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img-single column column-block">
       <a data-open="galleryModal">
       <img src="https://placeimg.com/440/780/animals" class="" alt="">
       </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img-single column column-block">
       <a data-open="galleryModal">
       <img src="https://placeimg.com/460/640/animals" class="" alt="">
       </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img-single column column-block">
       <a data-open="galleryModal">
       <img src="https://placeimg.com/720/420/animals" class="" alt="">
       </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img-single column column-block">
       <a data-open="galleryModal">
       <img src="https://placeimg.com/660/400/animals" class="" alt="">
       </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img-single column column-block">
       <a data-open="galleryModal">
       <img src="https://placeimg.com/480/840/animals" class="" alt="">
       </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img-single column column-block">
       <a data-open="galleryModal">
       <img src="https://placeimg.com/400/640/animals" class="" alt="">
       </a>
    </div>
    <div class="img-single column column-block">
       <a data-open="galleryModal">
       <img src="https://placeimg.com/440/780/animals" class="" alt="">
       </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.img-single {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    img {
      position: absolute;
      left: 50%;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      min-width: 300px;
      min-height: 300px;
    }
}
```

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tymothytym/41t9vkg9/3/)